# If I kill a caster with Mage Slayer does the spell still happen?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, reactions

Mage Slayer's first benefit says...

> When a creature within 5 feet of you casts a spell, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against that creature.

Does casting a spell encompass the entire spell effect or just the initation of the spell effect? If the latter, will the effect continue even if the caster dies from the Mage Slayer attack?

Comment: @Sdjz I dont know how i missed that question in my search. Lol

Answer (score 5):

If the spell is concentration, you would interrupt that, but the benefit specifically says you can only attack *when* the spell is cast, so instantaneous spells would still take effect.

> Some spells require you to maintain concentration
>   in order to keep their magic active. If you lose
>   concentration, such a spell ends.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Feel free to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). You may want to edit to mention that concentration isn't always broken on taking damage. Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I must have missed that. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: @DavidCoffron I think his point is that if the caster is dead, he isn’t concentrating on the spell any longer.

Comment: That said, I would definitely like to see more evidence that the timing of *when the spell is cast* is what you say it is. The tense of *is cast* is not nearly specific enough to come to that conclusion from the English text alone.

Comment: FYI: Concentration spell still takes place for the turn (turn, not round, in the event the caster fails) in which it was cast.